# No such file or directory error when using xargs

Tags: bash, ls, xargs

I have some files with `.mkv` extension and I want to calculate their total size using `du -h`. Some of the files are preceded by `whitespace` characters.

```
ranveer@ranveer:~$ ls *.mkv
Arrow.S01E02.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION_(1)  [SHYAMPAREEK.IN].mkv
mymediafirefreefreak.com_The.Mentalist.S05E04.480p.HDTV.X264-mRS.mkv
SHYAMPAREEK.IN-The.Vampire.Diaries.S04E02.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION_(1).mkv
Supernatural.S08E03.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION_(1)SHYAMPAREEK.IN].mkv
  [WWW.SHYAMPAREEK.IN].Arrow S01E01 480p HDTV.mkv
 [WWW.SHYAMPAREEK.IN].Castle.2009.S05E03.480p.HDTV.x264-mSD.mkv
ranveer@ranveer:~$
```

Now, I am using `xargs` to apply `du -h` to each of the files but for the files which are preceded by `whitespace` characters I am getting `No such file or directory` error.

```
ranveer@ranveer:~$ ls *.mkv | xargs -I f du -h "f" | awk '{print $1}'
du: cannot access `[WWW.SHYAMPAREEK.IN].Arrow S01E01 480p HDTV.mkv': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `[WWW.SHYAMPAREEK.IN].Castle.2009.S05E03.480p.HDTV.x264-mSD.mkv': No such file or directory
186M
151M
185M
186M
ranveer@ranveer:~$
```

But when I apply `du -h` to those files individually it works fine.

```
ranveer@ranveer:~$ du -h "  [WWW.SHYAMPAREEK.IN].Arrow S01E01 480p HDTV.mkv"
151M      [WWW.SHYAMPAREEK.IN].Arrow S01E01 480p HDTV.mkv
ranveer@ranveer:~$
```

So, why am I getting error when using the combination of `xargs & du -h`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need xargs in this case: `du -h -- *.mkv | awk '{print $1}'`

Anyway, to fix your problem `ls *.mkv | xargs du -h  | awk '{print $1}'`

[image]

Works for me, bash4.2

Comment: Thats even better but still curious why it is not working with `xargs`.

Comment: @RanRag because you have heading spaces in your filename, that wasn't a typo right?

Comment: @RanRag: parsing the output of `ls` is the problem. You have files with spaces at the beginning apparently, and that's being lost somewhere. Use `find -print0` and `xargs -0` if you need this sort of thing. (But better not use any of that if you actually don't need it.)

Comment: @RanRag solution posted

Comment: Yes, I know I have leading space that's why I wrapped the `xargs f` in `""`.

Comment: @warl0ck: The solution will not work in my case because I have leading `space` in the beginning of file and I have already mentioned this in my post/question.

Comment: @RanRag weird, that works for me, see screenshot

Comment: @warl0ck: doesn't work for me http://i.imgur.com/F6kJU.png

Comment: @RanRag try `ls -1` but just take the advice from Mat, don't parse the output of ls ...

Comment: @warl0ck: No change even after using `ls -1`. Lesson learned `do not try to parse the o/p of ls`. Thanks.

Comment: bro, stop parsing `ls`. Use `find -name '*.mkv' -print0 | xargs -0`

Answer (score 5):

Using `xargs` can be confusing sometimes. If you want to use it reliably, you either should make its input be `\0`-separated, i. e.

```
ls | tr \\n \\0 | xargs -0 stat
```

in order to change the newlines to `\0`s, or do (if you have a recent `xargs`)

```
ls | xargs -d \\n stat
```

Comment: please, why?? why??? `find -print0 | xargs -0 stat`

Answer (score 2):

Your command is a bit Rube Goldberg-esque. Take the list of files `*.mkv`. List those files (potentially replacing some nonprintable characters by an approximate representation). Parse the list (with some parsing rules that don't quite match the way the list is generated). Pass the individual parsed elements to the `du` command (which would be capable of taking multiple arguments).

The `ls` command doesn't expand wildcards, it's the shell that does. [Do not parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), it's practically never needed and often breaks something.

The input format of the `xargs` command doesn't match what any other command produces. Yes, it's bizarre. With `-I`, `xargs` ignores indentation, which is why the file names with initial spaces are mangled. Do not use `xargs` except with the `-0` option or when you know your input doesn't contain characters that would confuse it.

Just write

```
du -h *.mkv | awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `\` before your `ls`, e.g.: `\ls | xargs file`.

Comment: Could you explain why that would help in this case?

Comment: only in cases when `ls` is aliased to an option with color printing, because xargs don't know about ANSI codes and pass them through the next command

Comment: This was the correct answer for when searching for an answer to the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need "-0".

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html

> Because Unix filenames can contain blanks and newlines, this
> default behaviour is often problematic; filenames containing
> blanks and/or newlines are incorrectly processed by xargs.  In
> these situations it is better to use the -0 option, which
> prevents such problems.   When using this option you will need to
> ensure that the program which produces the input for xargs also
> uses a null character as a separator.  If that program is GNU
> find for example, the -print0 option does this for you.